# Name for this family of polynomials

Tags: polynomials

I have a multivariable polynomial with powers of variables equal to $1$ or $0$, e.g. 
$$
1=a+b+c-2ab-2bc-2ac+3abc.
$$
What is the name for this type of polynomial?

Comment: A first degree polynomial with $n$-variables? I haven't heard of a special name of this family

Comment: Is the $=$ intended ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this has a name. Notice that the RHS is

$$\left.\dfrac d{dx}(ax-1)(bx-1)(cx-1)\right|_{x=1},$$ which generalizes to more factors.

Comment: So it is just called a multivariable polynomial of degree 1?

Comment: @BenCrossley  It is a multivariate cubic. AFAIK there is no qualifier about the individual degrees, but I think you can call that a multiaffine polynomial, as it is affine in all variables.